# Can Mathematica use a MySQL ODBC connector?

Tags: databaselink, sql, databases

I have a MySQL database that I connect to using Mathematica and would like to distribute my Mathematica code to others. We already have ODBC DSNs setup on peoples machines using the MySQL ODBC connector. I've done a similar thing before in R using RODBC.

I attempted to use this;

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"];
JDBCDrivers["ODBC(DSN)"]
conn = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["ODBC(DSN)", "DatabaseName"]];
```

Which looked like it was going to work but after reading the documentation it seems that it uses a JDBC-ODBC bridge which I can't assume people have installed.

My question is can Mathematica use a ODBC connection (without a bridge) and if so how? If I have to use a JDBC connection then that's fine but I want to make sure that I'm not missing something.

Comment: Doesn't bring the standard mathematica installation such a preconfigured bridge, at least on Windows? From the DatabaseLink [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/DatabaseLink/tutorial/DatabaseConnections.html#8313): "DatabaseLink comes configured with a driver for ODBC connections". So I think you **can** assume it to be installed if people run your Mathematica code. On the other hand, if you are accessing a MySQL database, why not use the mysql-jdbc driver directly, which also seems to be delivered ready to use with DatabaseLink?

Comment: Thanks Albert. You're right the documentation does say that (the code that I posted came from the same page). I'll try to get the error message from the user and post it. I want to use a DSN instead of typing in the server location, that's why I'm not using the mysql-jdbc driver.